# Rx-java2 - Clearing a CompositeDisposable with doFinally operator

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm using rx-java2 to handle an asynchronous job in android app.

I'm creating a `Single<Long>`, I subscribe to it with a `DisposableSingleObserver` and the returned `Disposable`, I add to the `CompositeDisposable`.

```
// Instantiate a CompositeDisposable.
Composite mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

// Create a Single<Long>.
Single<Long> mDisposable= 
    Single
          .create(
                    new SingleOnSubscribe<Long>() {
                        @Override
                        public void subscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final SingleEmitter<Long> singleEmitter) throws Exception {
                            // Do a time consuming job and return a Long.
                        }
                    })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .doFinally(
                      new Action() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() throws Exception {
                                if(!mCompositeDisposable.isDisposed()){
                                    // Dispose of all Disposables in mCompositeDisposable.
                                    wCompositeDisposable.clear();
                                }
                            }
                      })
          // Subscribe and return a Disposable.           
          .subscribeWith(
                          new DisposableSingleObserver<Long>() {
                             // Handle success or error here.
                          })

// Add Disposable to mCompositeDisposable.
mCompositeDisposable.add(mDisposable);
```

Is it safe to clear `mCompositeDisposable` (disposing that way `mDisposable`) in Single's `doFinally()`? Although everything seems to work as intended when running the above code, it seems a little dangerous to dispose something from within its own stream.

Comment: For a long running operation you probably need a `Service`, not RxJava.

Comment: Although the emphasis of my question lies elsewhere, I changed 'long running opration' to 'asynchronous job'. And at least for that, RxJava is pretty damn good ;)

Comment: Fair enough! :) Anyway I didn't notice it was an old question. Did you find any answer?

Comment: `CompositeDisposable` is thread-safe, so that part is ok. Technically there is a race between adding `mDisposable` to `mCompositeDisposable` and `doFinally` -- it's possible, although unlikely, that `doFinally` runs before `mCompositeDisposable.add()`.

What is the purpose of doing this?